# How to locate an sqlite database using the sqlite3 command shell in mac?

Tags: database, macos, sqlite

I have an sqlite database that needs to be altered. I would like to use the sqlite3 command shell which is included on android adt bundle. I am not so familiar using sqlite3. I tried adding the sqlite database inside the adt bundle where the sqlite3 command shell is found and input in command shell the following commands

`.databases` - no database available

`select * from dbname;`  - Error: no such table:

By the way, the extension of the file is `dbname.sqlite`

I tried to study on this link: http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html but can't seem to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

SQlite doesn't have the concept of multiple databases, like SQL Server does, for example.

Just run the sqlite3 executable passing the name of the database file.

```
sqlite3 mydb.sql
```

Comment: @Grahan Perks Thanks. But I just altered my table on the other way. I used the Sqlite database browser. I delete the table I need to alter and recreate the table with modified sql.